# JS Конвертировать 32bit png изображение в 24bit

Tags: javascript

У меня есть некий canvas из которого я вытягиваю png изображение для печати, оно всегда 32bit. Ввиду того, что принтер печатает черно-белые 24bit изображения, то мне нужно преобразовать изображение из 32бит в 24бит. Как это можно сделать средствами javascript?

```
  const canv = document.createElement('canvas');
  const c = canv.getContext('2d');
  c.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```